# Remove tag and its content keyboard shortcut

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there a shortcut in sublime text 3 to remove an element and its contents?

I know selecting all element contents is CTRL+ALT+` (when selection is inside the element) and removing only the wrapping element but leaving the content is CTRL+SHIFT+; .

But I want to delete the element + content using keyboard shortcut. I need this for multiple selection.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, as I found was to:

1. Select all contents <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
2. Delete (<kbd>DEL</kbd>)
3. Delete tag <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>

Comment: not working for macos ST4

Comment: upd: 3. `Command` + `'` striping tag in macos

Comment: upd 9.2023: to remove outside tag Emmet is required, to enable this you should go to Emmet Key Bindings at Preferences, find Remove Tag section, copy it to the right side & uncomment